# Button within UITableViewCell not showing unless cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have 2 buttons within my UITableViewCell. One of them is shown by default, the other only shows when an action is performed once the first one is tapped. For some reason the buttons do not show unless the cell is selected. They used to show but I've obviously changed something and I don't know what. Any idea? Here's the relevant code:

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: EpisodesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EpisodesCell
    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: EpisodesCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CDEpisode
    cell.textLabel!.text = data.title
    cell.downloadButton.hidden = false
    cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "downloadButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    if data.isDownloaded == "yes" {
        cell.playButton.hidden = false
    }

}

class EpisodesCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var downloadButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func downloadEpisode(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(sender)
    println(sender.superview)
  }
}
```

Link to a screenshot of the cell: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACRiU8RKu9tEr58ULTBzIbk00h688Dt1q-w

Thank you

Comment: Selecting a cell actually converts all subview in the cell to background = clearColor. That said, is it possible that you have a view or something layered overtop of your buttons (covering them)? This would explain why they are visible on selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check this :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:

the code should be look like this :

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(button2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem. Though the right code is `cell.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(cell.downloadButton)`